# Hibernate: Populating UnMapped Component via HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Class A and Class B are entities mapped to their own database tables. Class C is NOT mapped and contains all the attributes of A and B. Is it possible to build a HQL to populate C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can use Hibernates [ResultTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html) for this:

```
List resultWithAliasedBean = s.createQuery(
  "select e.student.name as studentName," +
  "       e.course.description as courseDescription" +
  "from   Enrolment as e")
  .setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean(StudentDTO.class))
  .list();

StudentDTO dto = (StudentDTO) resultWithAliasedBean.get(0);
```